# The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify this software is installed

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, vagrant

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-dev
RUN apt-get install -y linux-image-$(uname -r)
RUN apt-get install -y curl net-tools jq
RUN apt-get autoclean
RUN apt-get autoremove
RUN curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/vagrant  | jq -r -M '.current_version')/vagrant_$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/vagrant  | jq -r -M '.current_version')_x86_64.deb
RUN dpkg -i vagrant_$(curl -s https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/vagrant  | jq -r -M '.current_version')_x86_64.deb
RUN vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt
RUN vagrant box add --provider libvirt peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval
RUN vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval
COPY startup.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/startup.sh"]
```

Hello friends! Dockerfile crashes when executing command:  docker build .

> ERROR [13/15] RUN vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval
> 2.9s
>
> [13/15] RUN vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval:

> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
> The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify this software is installed and on the path.

My host computer on windows 10

How to fix it?

Is it generally possible to implement this or not what would work?

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

This might state the obvious. But just to make sure:

It stumbles stumbles to initialize:

```
RUN vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval
```

after having tried to add it as `libvirt`-provider:

```
RUN vagrant box add --provider libvirt peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval
```

If I go to [libvirt's documentation](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt), then I can't find the notation you're trying to use.

### Solution suggestion

Try and replace that line with this:

```
RUN vagrant box add peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval --provider libvirt
```

... In case that the provider-flag needs to come after the name

Comment: Hello! Replaced the line as you said and already get another error. 

root@fe90f7c26aba:/opt/vagrant# vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

Vagrant is unable to use the VirtualBox provider from the Windows Subsystem for
Linux without access to the Windows environment. Enabling this access must be
done with caution and an understanding of the implications. For more information
on enabling Windows access and using VirtualBox from the Windows Subsystem for
Linux

Comment: The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.

Comment: ERROR [13/14] RUN vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval                                                                                                      
 > [13/14] RUN vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval:
#17 0.860 Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
#17 0.860
#17 0.860 The executable 'cmd.exe' Vagrant is trying to run was not
#17 0.860 found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify
#17 0.860 this software is installed and on the path.
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c vagrant init peru/windows-10-enterprise-x64-eval]: exit